# For loop for multiple ggplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this

```
Product <- c("X","Y","Z")
Var1 <- runif(3)
Var2 <- rnorm(3)
Var3 <- rnorm(3)

df <- data.frame(Product,Var1,Var3,Var2)

bar.plot <- function(dat,k,p,this) {
  mytitle <- paste("Topic:",as.character(this))
  ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = substitute(k), y = substitute(p))) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity",fill="lightblue", colour="black") +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold"), axis.text.y =   element_text(size=20),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10,angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
    labs(title=mytitle)
}
```

I want the following to return three plots for each of my columns in `df`. It doesn't though.

```
col <- c(Var1,Var2,Var3)
for(i in col){
bar.plot(df,Product,i,"Data")
}
```

Any ideas why this might be? Thanks.

Comment: Check content of `col` variable. You should pass "Product", "Var1" etc as character to ggplot function call.

Comment: Where did you expect to return them to? You didn't seem to make an attempt to store them anywhere. `for` loops don't return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DrDom says, you need characters in your `col`, and if you want to see the plots you need to `print` them inside a for loop. (Or save them, or assign them in a `list`...)

```
col <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")
for(i in col){
    print(bar.plot(df, Product, i, "Data"))
}
```

While this will work just fine with your original `bar.plot`, the `substitute` is entirely unnecessary (you're already using `aes_string`!), so we could simplify to:

```
bar.plot <- function(dat,k,p,this) {
    mytitle <- paste("Topic:", as.character(this))
    ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = k, y = p)) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity",
                 fill = "lightblue", colour = "black") +
        theme(plot.title=element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
              axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
        labs(title = mytitle)
}
```

Comment: hm I am getting  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach.

```
bar.plot <- function(dat,k,p,this) {
  mytitle <- paste("Topic:",as.character(this))
  gg      <- data.frame(x=dat[,k],y=dat[,p])
  ggplot(gg, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity",fill="lightblue", colour="black") +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold"), axis.text.y =   element_text(size=20),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10,angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
    labs(title=mytitle)
}
for(i in 2:4){
  print(bar.plot(df,"Product",i,"Data"))
}
```

This builds a data frame with columns `x` and `y` inside the function, and uses that in the call to `ggplot(...)`, rather than trying to use `aes_string(...)`.

Your code: `col <- c(Var1,Var2,Var3)` creates a vector length 9 basically concatenating the three Var columns. When you use `for (i in col)` R sets i to the value of each element in col in sequence, so the loop runs 9 times - not what you want.